# Posh-SSH to send multiple commands to Cisco Switch

Tags: powershell, ssh, posh-ssh

I am attempting to automate a process where I have a powershell script SSH into our cisco switch and open and close a Vlan interface. When I try to run it I get **"Exception calling "EndExecute" with "1" argument(s): "An established connection was aborted by the server.""**

What is missing from my script that is causing it to error out like this? Thanks.

```
Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH

#Set Creds
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$secpasswd = "myPass"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secpasswd -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myUser", $secpasswd)

#Build SSH session
New-SSHSession "MyIP" -Port 22 -Credential $mycreds
#Assign current session to Var.
$s = Get-SSHSession | Select -ExpandProperty SessionID -First 1

#Send SSH Commands
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command "show log" -SessionId $s
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command "conf t" -SessionId $s
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command "interface vlan 310" -SessionId $s
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command "shut" -SessionID $s
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command "no shut" -SessionID $s
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command "exit" -SessionId $s
Invoke-SSHCommand -Command "exit" -SessionId $s

#Close SSH-Session
Remove-SSHSession -SessionId $s
```

Comment: You need to use the SSHShellStream option with Cisco equipment, as mentioned here - https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/issues/146

Answer (score 0):

Try with SSHShellStream > SSHStreamShellCommand

```
$SSHsession=New-SSHSession -ComputerName $YourSwitchIP -Credential $Cred -AcceptKey 
$SSHStream = New-SSHShellStream -Index $SSHsession.SessionId
#---> Enter conf
$cmd="conf"
Invoke-SSHStreamShellCommand -ShellStream $SSHStream -Command $cmd
```